# What are these legs to connect to an IC called on a PCB?

Tags: pcb, identification, pcb-assembly

I am designing my first PCB and it is going to be designed to plug into IC sockets on a motherboard (replacement modern RAM for retro computers).

I was wondering what to use for the legs. Looking through my retro drawer I have found something that I love, but I can't find any references for it online or how to achieve it.

I have added top and bottom PCB shots of what I am searching for.

[image: Bottom of board pins]

[image: Top of board pins]

Comment: Pin Header? https://www.google.com/search?q=pin+header

Comment: Are the IC sockets ones which are already on the motherboard or will you be soldering on the sockets yourself, so that you would have a choice of type of socket? If the latter then maybe you could use turned-pin sockets and round pin headers.

Comment: @AndrewMorton I am adding the sockets myself at the moment, I hope to opensource my work though so others can use it, so having the most flexible option is best

Comment: this question shows what you may be looking for ... https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/651880/what-are-dip-adapter-headers-used-for

Answer (score 4):

The legs you show are common rectangular pins - perhaps with custom flat tops that got lots of solder on them - and are a **rather bad choice** for use with DIP sockets. DIP sockets are designed for pins that are relatively thin and have a rectangular cross section - **not** for round or square cross-section pins!

For such projects, the only choice that doesn't damage the sockets is a proper DIP leadframe. The sources are limited, but they are IMHO the only solutions that preserve socket integrity. [Batten&Allen are a good source](https://leadframes.co.uk/#dualinline) and a standard to aspire to. Alternatively, [Flip Pins from OSH Chip](http://oshchip.org/products/Flip-Pins_Product.html) are a viable alternate and certainly better than using rectangular or round pins.

Unfortunately, at the moment these are the only two readily available options that are in current manufacture as far as I know. I wish there was more competition in that space.

If you care about your customers and the preservation of their gear, it's highly recommended to do the right thing. Even if you're serious about preserving your *own* retro computers, it'd be the right choice.