# What are DIP component carriers used for?

Tags: connector, adapter, dip

I was looking for SOP16 to DIP16 adapters, and I came across this [Connector DIP Adapter Header 16 Position 2.54mm Solder Straight Through Hole](https://www.jameco.com/z/16-600-10-Aries-Electronics-Connector-DIP-Adapter-Header-16-Position-2-54mm-Solder-Straight-Through-Hole_291574.html).

[image]

What is it and what does it adapt between?

Comment: Connecting wires to a dip socket maybe?

Comment: discrete components

Comment: somebody was looking for this very thing a few days ago here

Answer (score 5, accepted):

DIP headers can be used to adapt discrete components, wire jumpers or cables to a DIP socket. This can be used to make small modules that can be plugged in and easily swapped, for instance one product I worked with used them to change resistors and capacitors in a filter circuit for different requirements. Another one used them with jumpers to configure a single board computer's memory and I/O configuration, the board had a dip socket and depending on what options the customer ordered we would plug in a header with the correct jumpers. If they wanted to upgrade later, say by adding more RAM, we would send them the new RAM chips and the header jumpered for the new configuration.

You can see one used like this at the top of this image.
[image: dip header on circuit board]

Comment: Also useful for wire-wrap boards, where 99% were chips and there were just a few discrete components.

Answer (score 5):

That's a "[DIP component carrier](https://connectorbook.com/identification.html?m=NNK&n=dip_component_carriers)". (My site).

[image: DIP component carrier]

It is (was) used to carry through-hole components to make a small module that would then be plugged into a DIP socket. That allows fast customization of a board in the field. For example, they are still used in Audio Mixer console at my radio station to set the gain and filtering of each channel.

Comment: I think you guys need to invest in a DSP