# DC-DC flyback transformer (SMT)

Tags: transformer, dc-dc-converter, inductor, surface-mount, flyback

I am building a flyback DC-DC converter for a school project and am new to soldering and power electronics. I want to prototype the design on a breadboard first, now that I have the design equations calculated, but finding a suitable through-hole transformer to match my desired magnetizing inductance and turns ratio has been difficult.

I want to keep my turns ratio 1:1 to minimize the secondary side current (I do not want to exceed 1 A on a breadboard), so I have been looking at coupled inductors and found one on Coilcraft that will work. The exact part number is [MSD1514-105KE](https://www.coilcraft.com/en-us/products/power/coupled-inductors/1-1-shielded-coupled/msd/msd1514/?skuId=13155)

The problem is that it's a surface mount component, and I have not been able to find a suitable breakout board that I can solder this onto to pin it to a breadboard. Does anyone know how I can find a compatible breakout board for this coupled inductor?

Comment: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/651880/what-are-dip-component-carriers-used-for

Comment: Solder pins to the transformer. It has now become a through hole part. However, it may be a bad idea to use a bread board for prototyping a switch mode power supply, due to high frequencies, fast voltage changes, and high current.

Comment: Spend the time to learn to solder. You are bound to at the very least struggle constantly and probably fail if you limit yourself to breadboard and THT. KiCad is free and a custom PCB is 5 USD with a few days of turnover.

Comment: Should be no problem soldering wires to the part. Prototyping switched mode supplies on breadboard is probably not a good idea - you have high frequencies and high currents. These don’t mix well with breadboards.